# protractor fdescribe and fit does not work with jasmine-reporters

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I have this in my conf.js

```
onPrepare: function() {
    /**if comment out then spec runs, if uncomment then spec doesn't run
    var jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter({
    consolidateAll: true,
    filePrefix: 'portal_tests_xmloutput',
        savePath: './test_results_report'
      })); **/
    },      
};
```

in my test_spec.js I have

```
fdescribe('my tests', function() {

it('test1', function(){
});

fit('test2', function(){
});

it('test3', function(){
});

}
```

When I run my tests it will output

```
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
Started


No specs found
Finished in 0.002 seconds
```

if I comment out the jasmine reporters declaration in my conf.js and run again it will run the correct test and output

```
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
Started
test2
.


1 spec, 0 failures
Finished in 5.675 seconds
```

Why is jasmine-reporters interfering with focused spec testing? I would like to have jasmine-reporters enable while running with fdescribe and fit. I'm using

protractor: 1.8.0
jasmine-reporters: 2.0.4

Answer (score 3):

The problem is solved in `jasmine-reporters@2.0.5`.

Apparently when using `fit`, jasmine does not call the `suiteStarted` or `suiteDone` callbacks. `jasmine-reporters` relies upon these methods being called, and was blowing up as a result. As of 2.0.5, it now tries to detect if these methods have been called and adapt.

Comment: Nice catch - was wondering why it stopped working. The upgrade didn't fix it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Did you provide the `framework='jasmine2'` setting in your config file? https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/referenceConf.js#L253